# How to set API Rate Limiting for every user in Lumen?

Tags: php, lumen

I have an API in the Lumen framework and I need to set a limit to calling this API for every `user_id`.

So I need to limit calling this API just once per minute.

Answer (score 0):

**I found the answer in this:**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;

$user_id = request('user_id');
$executed = RateLimiter::attempt(
    'send-message:'.$user_id,
    1, //request number
    function() { },
    5 //per_sec
);
if (!$executed) {
    throw new TooManyRequestsException(__('errors.too_many_request'));
 }
```